# DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow makes the entire client area transparent

Tags: winapi, aero-glass

Aero glass causes alot of people problems trying to draw on it. Anything with an alpha value of 255 seems to be treated as transparent with DWM using an additive blur to draw it. I want a part of client area to use Aero glass with the rest of it treated as opaque, so I don't have to deal with the headache of common controls not rendering properly.

MSDN lists a function `DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow` which lets you mark part of the client area as blurred by DWM. It takes a `DWM_BLURBEHIND` pointer which which has an `HRGN` handle to the region of the window. When I use this function, the entire window becomes transparent with an additive blend, but only the region of the window I passed to `DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow` gets blurred. Is there a way I can keep the rest of the window from becoming transparent?

What I have looks a bit like:

```
blur.dwFlags = DWM_BB_ENABLE | DWM_BB_BLURREGION;
blur.hRgnBlur = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 90, 90);
blur.fEnable = true;
DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(hwnd, &blur);
RECT rect;
GetClientArea(&rect);
FillRect(hdc, &rect, CreateSolidBrush(0));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MSDN Library article:

> The alpha values in the window are honored and the rendering atop the blur will use these alpha values. It is the applications responsiblity for ensuring that the alpha values of all pixels in the window are correct. Some GDI operations do not perserve alpha values so care must be taken when presenting child windows as the alpha values they contribute are unpredicitable.

Make that *most* GDI operations, like FillRect().  The brush you created is drawn with 24-bit colors, the alpha will be 0.  Which makes the window transparent.  You'll need to switch to, say, GDI+.  Text is particularly troublesome.  As well as legacy Windows controls, like EDIT and LISTBOX which draw with GDI.

Comment: Yeah, reading closer I also found this "When you apply the blur-behind effect to a subregion of the window, the alpha channel of the window is used for the nonblurred area. This can cause an unexpected transparency in the nonblurred region of a window. Therefore, be careful when you apply a blur effect to a subregion."

Dang. DWM also has a weird way of "honoring" alpha, since at alpha 254 it's essentially opaque, but at alpha 255 it does additive blending, as I've tested with GDI+.